# iphone-webservice-image

Tags: iphone

i want to display image in uitableviewcell,
for that in uitableview my data is fetch from webservice
and i use xmlparsing for that 
i.e.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
}
```

Now , If My XML Ouput Return Image Path Name,,

> Like hhtp://www.abc.com/a.png

then uitableviewcell can display image ?

If Not Then How I Can Display Image...

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/a.png"]];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = img;
    [img release];
    [data release];
```

Comment: If the image is large you might want to load it in a thread and show a UIActivityIndicator until it's loaded, but yea that code should work.

Comment: yeah...taht absolutely ture... but I'm assuming that your images are small as your are going to show them in tableviewcell, one more thing if your rows are very large then you can use lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
id path = @"http://www.abc.com/a.png";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO]
cell.imageView.image = img;
```